# How to intepret cotangent laplacian?

Tags: differential-geometry, computational-geometry

[image]

I have the above slide in my lecture notes. The question is why do people define such things? How is it useful?

Answer (score 4):

"The question is why do people define such things? How is it useful?"
The so-called cotangent Laplacian and other sorts of [discrete] Laplacians (e.g. another famous example the so-called [combinatorial Laplacian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplacian_matrix) in Graph Theory $L=D-A$) are supposedly all approximating [the continuous Laplacian operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_operator) (functional), that takes the Divergence of the Gradient of a scalar function/field. When you have a discrete version of this operator, you can solve a large class of differential equations involving the Laplacian such as the Laplace and Poisson equations that appear as governing equations explaining phenomena such as heat diffusion in solids. Suppose you wanted to solve a heat equation on a mesh approximating a metal surface (say the cover of an engine) and that you wanted to find out the steady-state of the heat distribution (temperature actually) on this surface. The smooth surface would be approximated by a triangular mesh and so you would use the discrete Laplacian to approximate the heat equation. Long story short, you would end up with a system of linear equations to solve instead of a differential equation. This simplification of differential equations to linear equations is the advantage of using discrete differential operators such as this Laplacian; especially in cases where analytic solutions are impractical to find; i.e. in cases where the only way to solve a [PDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_differential_equation) is using numerical methods and discretization. Note that the input and solution functions in this approach are approximated or discretized on the vertices of the mesh.

Answer (score 3):

It is actually not a definition, it is a *consequence*, at least in the context of the finite element method (FEM).

Imagine you have a function $f_i$ defined on each node $i$. Then, you can interpolate
$$
\bar{f}(r) = \sum_i f_i \phi_i(r) ,
$$
where $\phi_i(r)$ is an interpolating function (a "shape function"). You may take tent-shaped functions, in 2D $\phi_i(r)$ looks like a camping tent, with value $1$ at $i$ and a base made up of all triangles incident to $i$ (you need an underlying triangulation, and the Delaunay is a good candidate.)

If you want to obtain the Laplacian of a function, you may want to approximate the Laplacian as
$$
\nabla^2 \bar{f}(r) = \sum_i f_i \nabla^2 \phi_i(r) ,
$$
but these functions cannot be differentiated twice! One way to circumvent this is by noting that you usually want the Laplacian at some node:
$$
\nabla^2 f_i  = \int dr \phi_i(r) (\nabla^2 \bar{f}(r) ) =
\int dr \phi_i(r)  \sum_j f_j \nabla^2 \phi_j(r)  ,
$$
where you are now using your interpolating functions to do the opposite task of going from a continuum function to a value defined on nodes only. (Actually, this formula lacks something called "the mass matrix", which in its simplest form means you have to divide by $1/3$ the area of your tent.)
Now, the trick is to use integration by parts, and write
$$
\nabla^2 f_i  =
\sum_j f_j  \int dr \phi_i(r)   \nabla^2 \phi_j(r)  =
- \sum_j f_j  \int dr \nabla \phi_i(r) \cdot  \nabla \phi_j(r)  .
$$
That integrand will only be non-zero in the region on which the shape functions $\phi_i$ and $\phi_j$ overlap, which is the two triangles that lie on either side of the edge connecting them. The integration is easy, since both gradients are just constant vectors. For instance, in one triangle $\phi_i$ will be a vector pointing directly towards vertex $i$ from opposite side (i.e. in the direction of the [altitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Altitude_(triangle))), and with modulus $1/h_1$, where $h_1$ is the length of the altitude. With this, and taking into account
the scalar product, you can simplify that integral and show that
$$
\int dr \nabla \phi_i(r) \cdot  \nabla \phi_j(r)  =
-\frac12 \cot\alpha_{ij} .
$$

[This](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Ekmcrane/Projects/Other/nDCotanFormula.pdf) is a nice set of notes for these issues. Also, notice the true Laplacian still lacks that "mass", see [mesh Laplacians on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Laplace_operator#Mesh_Laplacians).